# Custom Model Validation based on two properties. One influence the other one

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, validation, validationattribute

I Use Asp.Net MVC 2 with entity framework 4.
Here is the situation : I Have a checkbox and a textbox(Date Picker).
If the checkbox is checked, the textbox is required. If the checkbox is false, the textbox is not required. 
Checkbox True => Textbox Required 
Checkbox False => Textbox not required

```
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.oEnvironment.Remediate) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.oEnvironment.DatePick)%>
```

I know how to create a ValidationAttribute but I dont know how to create a validation class that verify if the checkbox is checked (if my Entity Remediate Attribute is true) and then put the DatePick field as required.

Any Idea ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need client validation, I suggest that you use `ModeState.AddModelError` to test your logic (in your controller).

Something like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
        if (model.Remediate && string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.DatePick))
            ModelState.AddModelError("DatePickRequired", "DatePick is required");
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);
        return View();
}
```

Gtz,

Stéphane.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to implement the [IDataErrorInfo](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validating-with-the-idataerrorinfo-interface-cs) interface on your model, although I haven't ever tried this myself.

Comment: Is anybody has an other idea.

Answer (score 0):

As a totally different approach, you could take a look at the Fluent Validation project http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/ which plays well with MVC via an inversion of control container http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation and http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/02/22/using-fluentvalidation-with-an-ioc-container/

This should enable you to code this and similar rules really well, and the IOC articles show how to integrate into MVC<3

(not strictly an answer as you stated MVC2 but an upgrade to MVC3 would make this easier too as it supports model level validation http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#BM_Model_Validation_Improvements )

Answer (score 0):

For complex validation, just perform the validation in the action (or anywhere on the server side).