# How do I stop further validation if one fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Ive just recently started using [jquery validation engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine), and I was wondering:

Im in a scenario where I only want to validate a field only if another field isnt empty. I have applied the condRequired validation rule to this field, which works fine, but all other rules after the condRequired get fired. For example:

```
<input type="password" id="current-password" name="current-password" placeholder="Current Password" class="validate[condRequired[password],ajax[ajaxValidateUserPassword]]"> 
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password" class="ajax[ajaxValidateUserRegistration]]">
```

If a user decides they want to update their password, they must enter the current password. However I only want to validate the current password, if the user has entered a new password. So I have:

```
validate[condRequired[password],ajax[ajaxValidateUserPassword]]
```

as the validation rule on the current password. The problem is: even if the user hasn't entered a new password,

```
condRequired[password]
```

will fail, but

```
ajax[ajaxValidateUserPassword]
```

still gets fired.

Is there a way to get the

```
ajax[ajaxValidateUserPassword]
```

validation rule to get skipped if the

```
condRequired[password]
```

rule fails? Idea is I dont want to bother with ANY validation on the current password if no new password has been entered

Thanks!

Comment: you're looking for `requiredif`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052571/unobtrusive-validation-c-sharp-mvc-razor (Just the javascript part)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not.

Answer (score 0):

ValidationEngine allows you to specify a validation rule which uses a custom function to determine validity.

```
<input value="" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]]" type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />

function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options){
  if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
     // this allows the use of i18 for the error msgs
     return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
  }
}
```

From within that function you can call any ajax to validate field if "New Password" is not empty

Comment: Thanks Andriy, I saw this but I was hoping there was a more elegant way? Im guessing this is my best bet

Answer (score 0):

Use the option "maxErrorsPerField":

```
$("form").validationEngine({
    maxErrorsPerField: 1
});
```