# ASP.NET MVC3. How to set validation to require one of two fields depending on bool value of the model?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

Here is my model:

```
public class RestoreRequestModel : IDataErrorInfo
{
    //true seems Value contains phone email otherwise
    public bool IsPhoneMode { get; set; }

    //Contains phone or email address.
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>RestoreModel</legend>

    <label for="email">By Email</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsPhoneMode, Constants.RESTORE_BY_EMAIL, new { id="email" })

    <label for="phone">By Phone</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.IsPhoneMode, Constants.RESTORE_BY_PHONE, new { id = "phone" })

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Value)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>}
```

Is it possible to set validation depending on model.IsPhoneMode state? I can set validation by adding attributes to the model properties but there must be different validation conditions depending on RadioButton state.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC Conditional validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is to implement your own attribute that makes a conditional requirement there are lots of blog posts that you can search about that topic or you can download [Mvc.ValidationTookit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/09/29/mvc-validationtookit-alpha-release-conditional-validation-with-mvc-3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Nuget the FoolProof validation package.  It is fully featured for situations like this.