# Data Annotation with Bools

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model, data-annotations

Down below I have three different categories.

How would I structure the validation to make sure that at least one boolean gets selected per category?

//Disabilities

```
    [Display(Name = "Learning Disabilities")]
    public bool LD { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Developmental Disabilities")]
    public bool DD { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "AD/HD")]
    public bool ADHD { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Autism")]
    public bool Autism { get; set; }
```

//Age Group

```
    [Display(Name = "Child")]
    public bool child { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Youth")]
    public bool youth { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Adult")]
    public bool adult { get; set; }
```

//Strategy Type

```
    [Display(Name = "Academic")]
    public bool academic { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Behaviour")]
    public bool behaviour { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Communication")]
    public bool communication { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Social")]
    public bool social { get; set; }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC3. How to set validation to require one of two fields depending on bool value of the model?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143151/asp-net-mvc3-how-to-set-validation-to-require-one-of-two-fields-depending-on-bo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider using a different model. If what you are trying to do is enforce at least one selection per category then it may be better to group them together and use a required attribute.

```
public enum Age
{
  [Display(Name="Child")
  Child,
  [Display(Name="Youth")
  Youth,
  [Display(Name="Adult")
  Adult
}
```

Then have a property on your model like so:

```
[Required]
public Age MyAge { get; set; }
```