# Validating same property in a model in same view using mutually exclusive validations using Data annotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a requirement where I need to validate the dropdown. On a Button1 click the Model should validate that the dropdown is not selected and on Button2 click the Model should validate that the dropdown is selected to a valid value and also a corresponding field is also  marked as Required if the Value is a certain value from the dropdown.

My model is as below:

```
public class ApprovalInformation
{

    [DisplayName("Approval Decision")]
    public int? ApproveStatusID { get; set; }
    public string ApproveStatus { get; set; }
    public SelectList ApproveStatuses { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Additional Information")]
    [RequiredIf("ApproveStatus", StringConstants.NotApproved, ErrorMessage = "You must specify the comments if not approved")]
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
}
```

Currently I have  2 action methods and I call them based on the value of the button name. Here is the controller code:

```
public ActionResult SaveApproval(ApprovalInformation approveInfo,string submit)
    {
        if (submit == "Save For Later")
        {
            Business business = new Business();
            int selectedStatusID = approveInfo.ApproveStatusID??0;
            if ( selectedStatusID!= 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("ApproveStatusID", "You may not set the Approval Decision before saving a service request for later.  Please reset the Approval Decision to blank");
            }
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
              return RedirectToActionPermanent("EditApproval");
            }

            return View("EditApproval", approveInfo);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["approverInfo"] = approveInfo;
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("FinishApproval");
        }
    }
```

I am having a problem plugging the validation depending on the buttons clicked. Since on different button click the same property should be validated in 2 different manner. How can i suppress a Validation or Induce validations at run time on the same model depending on different actions. Any idea around this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a good situation to implement the [IValidatableObject Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate.aspx) on your `ApprovalInformation` view model. You can pass through the intent to `submit` or `save for later` in the `ValidationContext` dictionary, in order to get the reuse you need.

You can also place the [conditional logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation) that "AdditionalInformation must be set if ApprovalStatus is not set" here, as well.

```
public class ApprovalInformation : IValidatableObject
{
    ... // Properties

    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       if (validationContext.ContainsKey("submit"))
       {
          if (ApproveStatusID != 0)
          {
              yield return new ValidationResult("You may not set the Approval Decision before saving a service request for later.  Please reset the Approval Decision to blank", 
                                                 new {"ApproveStatusID"});
          }
       }
    }
}
```