# Optional Validation for Change Password in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have the following model

```
public AccountInfo {

    // loads of other property here as well.

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "New Passwords dont match.")]
    public string ConfirmNewPassword { get; set; }

}
```

I am using data annotations to display client side validation message.

Now I am working on the change user profile details page.

What I am required to do is, Along with the other details such as email, full name, address etc, I have to show 3 fields namely

- Current password
- New password
- Confirm New password

Now the scene is that these are optional fields and user may not fill it. But when he does, **I want to make sure all the 3 fields are filled.**, if not I want to show some validation error using data annotation.

Any Thoughts ?

Comment: There is a bunch of results regarding the conditional validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/10/06/flexible-conditional-validation-with-asp-net-mvc-3 http://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: this solution does not work with client side validation

Comment: Check this link, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

Comment: It's not only server side, didn't you see the javascript code snippets which is for unontrusive validation on client side?

Comment: but that's not using data annotation right ? I wanted to do this using data annotations

Comment: As I read he's developed a custom annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any built in data annotation for this. You could create your custom attribute to do the validation, but it's not easy. As such, I would suggest you to use Jquery Validation / Javascript to handle this.

Basically you would want to override the submit event and do your own validation logic in there. You code will be similar to this:

```
function SubmitToServer() { 
    if ($('#Password').length == 0 || ($('#Password').length > 0 && $('#NewPassword ').length > 1 && $(formId).valid()) {
        $(formId).submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: did client side validation using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[Required]` to tell the RAZOR that these are must or mandatory like that..

```
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }

 [Required]
 public string NewPassword { get; set; }

 [Required]
 [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "New Passwords dont match.")]
 public string ConfirmNewPassword { get; set; }
```

If you want to Provide range of value means use this one - `[Range(1, 100)]`

If you want to use password lenght means use this one - `[StringLength(5)]`

Comment: thanks for your answer, BUT this is not what I am looking for. please read the question again. I want to make sure all the 3 fields are filled if even one of them is filled and they can all be empty also.