# How do I turn off request validation in MVC2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I needs to find a way to allow html tags in MVC2 model binding.

In MVC3 there is a way but MVC2 I dont know. can you help?

In MVC3

```
[AllowHtml]
public string SomeProperty{ get; set; }
```

I need some alternate method for AllowHtmlAttribute in mvc2

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute on the controller action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

This will disable input validation for all properties of the model. There's no way in ASP.NET MVC 2 to do this per property - it has to be for the entire request.

Comment: I need remove validation for one property not for all. Are there any way to do it?

Comment: No, sorry, I am afraid there's no such feature in ASP.NET MVC 2. There's quite a lot of the entire stack that has to be rewritten in order to support it.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation