# Custom validation in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have a dropdown list conatining some options. The last one is "other". When the user chooses the `other` option a textbox appears next to the drop down list. When the user chooses "other" he must enter a value into the textbox. Both, the dropdown list and the textbox, point to one single property of the the model. 
How do I achieve this using custom validation? what is the best solution?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: It really depends on a lot of things. What type is the "value" of the dropdown? If it's `int`, then you have a chance using annotations. If not, my bet would be on JavaScript.

Comment: the value is int and text is string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're looking for is **conditional validation**. A very nice example is [already mentioned in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation) where you could create a custom `RequiredIf` attribute.

The topic has [also been addressed  frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+conditional+validation) on stackoverflow.com

Comment: thanks but conditional validation is for two properties of the model. as I wrote both textbox and dropdown list are for one property.