# Custom Required attribute - property required depending of parent model value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, required-field

I have a model ProductModel which has:
* bool IsNew property
* ProductDetailsModel Details property

```
public class ProductModel
{
    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
    public ProductDetails Details { get; set; }
}

public class ProductDetails
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

ProductDetails has some other properties eg. Code, Type, Description, Number

I would like to make Description and Number property of ProductDetailsModel required only if *IsNew* of *ProductModel* is set to true.

How to do it?

BTW I have more properties of custom types within ProductModel and I can't move their properties into single ProductModel.

Comment: This is more 'business logic' rather than something that should be done inside a model.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here [ASP.NET MVC Conditional validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation)

It seems the easiest way to do it to implement validation in the Product model.