# VB/MVC: Server side model validation with condition

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a ASP.NET MVC5-applikation that is built in VB.
I have a form that gets data to a viewmodel, and I want to add server side validation to the field Age, but only if Alive is true.
Here is my model:

```
Public Class MyViewModel
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Age As Integer
  Public Property Alive As Boolean
End Class
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400542/how-do-i-use-ivalidatableobject) question on SO. VB does not have Yield, so I tried the following:

```
Public Function Validate(validationContext As ValidationContext) As Enumerable(Of ValidationResult) Implements IValidatableObject.Validate
        Dim results As List(Of ValidationResult) = New List(Of ValidationResult)
        If Alive And Age > 120 Then
            results.Add(New ValidationResult("Too old."))

        Else
            results.Add(ValidationResult.Success)
        End If
        Return results
    End Function
```

Now, I get a null reference exception.
How do I implement conditional validation in VB?

Comment: Um, you're living in the past.  VB does support `Yield`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156729.aspx

Comment: @jmcilhinney Ok, thank you.