# Skip all the validation of a model base on one of its property (ASP.Net Core 2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core

How I can skip all the validation of a model base on one of its property. For instance, if the `WillBeDeleted` property of the object is true the validator skips all the validation rules.

```
namespace ViewModel
{
    public class ContactForm : IViewModel
    {
        [ValidateNever]
        public Contact Item { get; set; }

        public Category Category { get; set; }

        [Required, DisplayName("First name")]
        [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "First name should not exceed 200 characters.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required, DisplayName("Last name")]
        [StringLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Last name should not exceed 200 characters.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public List<TelephonesSubForm> Telephones { get; set; } = new List<TelephonesSubForm>();

        public List<EmailsSubForm> Emails { get; set; } = new List<EmailsSubForm>();

        public class TelephonesSubForm : IViewModel
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public bool MustBeDeleted { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public TelephoneAndEmailType Type { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Telephone should not exceed 200 characters.")]
            public string Telephone { get; set; }
        }

        public class EmailsSubForm
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }

            public bool MustBeDeleted { get; set; }

            [Required]
            public TelephoneAndEmailType Type { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(200, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Email should not exceed 200 characters.")]
            public string Email { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

In the given sample model, when the `MustBeDeleted` is `true` it means that the item of email or telephone will be deleted on the save action.

I have searched and found that several questions about conditional (custom) validation and they are suggesting to remove the specific keys from the `ModelState` before checking the validation state of it. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation) one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding a New answer and keep the old as it could be usefull to someone

So, Create a Custom Attribute:

```
  public class CustomShouldValidateAttribute : Attribute, IPropertyValidationFilter
  {
    public CustomShouldValidateAttribute(){

    }
    public bool ShouldValidateEntry(ValidationEntry entry, ValidationEntry parentEntry)
    {
      //Here you change this verification to Wether it should verificate or not, In this case we are checking if the property is ReadOnly (Only a get method)
      return !entry.Metadata.IsReadOnly;      
    }
  }
```

and them on your class you decorate it with your custom attribute

```
[CustomShouldValidateAttribute]
public class MyClass{
public string Stuff{get;set;}
public string Name {get{return "Furlano";}}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although It is not the complete answer for the question, It is possible to inherit validation attributes (`RequiredAttribute`, `StringLength`, [etc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation#validation-attributes)) and override the `IsValid` method. As a sample, I provide one of them.

```
public class RequiredWhenItIsNotDeletingAttribute : RequiredAttribute
{
    string DeletingProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the object is going to be deleted skip the validation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deletingProperty">The boolean property which shows the object will be deleted.</param>
    public RequiredWhenItIsNotDeletingAttribute(string deletingProperty = "MustBeDeleted") =>
        DeletingProperty = deletingProperty;

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var property = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(DeletingProperty);

        if((bool)property.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance))
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inherit your model from IValidatableObject

and implement the interface method:

```
  public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

      if (YourCondition==false){
        yield return new ValidationResult(
          $"This is wrong",
          new[] { nameof(Email) });
      }
      else
         yield return ValidationResult.Success

    }
```

But you will have to implemment a validation foreach property of yours and exclude decorations you have already written!

Answer (score -1):

You can call the method:

```
ModelState.Clear()
```

when MustBeDeleted is true

Comment: Thank you @EricImhauser, At the last paragraph of the question I used a link which contains your answer. In addition, If I clear the entire model state all the validation would be deleted while I need to avoid all the validation related to one of the items of TelephonesSubForm or EmailsSubForm.

Comment: What is the problem with deleting individual items from the ModelState in the subforms?

Comment: There are two problems with it, first of all, it would lead to doing more process which is useless. validating and removing its result. Second of all, it is better to solve the solution with an attribute or something like that, which coded once for all the actions, rather than removing validation result in all the actions.

Comment: It (second of all, ...) is the reason why I prefer the other answer.