# Get error "Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined" when adding jquery validation rules to ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a date field that is required only if a text field has a value and vice versa.

Since it's conditional I can't just use the required attribute on the C# class, ie.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
```

So for the `onChange` event of both fields I run this function:

```
function validateTermination()
{
    if ($('#TerminationDate').val() == null && $('#TerminationReason').val() == null)
    {
        //remove validation
        $('#TerminationDate').rules('remove');
        $('#TerminationReason').rules('remove');
    }
    else
    {
        //add validation
        $('#TerminationDate').rules('add', { required: true });
        $('#TerminationReason').rules('add', { required: true });
    }
}
```

Both of the add rule statements cause the error to throw. The error occurs in the jquery.validate.js file here:

```
var settings = $.data(element.form, "validator").settings;
```

I guess `$.data(element.form, "validator")` is null for some reason, although I'm at a loss as to why.

Comment: JSYK, you can create a custom validation attribute when a requirement is conditional.

Comment: I think the answer for conditional validation you are looking for is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417113/asp-net-mvc-conditional-validation

Comment: @godfathr That doesn't work on client side.

Comment: @quiqs I've seen posts about that but they never work client side.

Comment: @Legion The marked answer doesn't work client side, but the thread contains another answer using Expressive annotations that does. It's the third answer down. https://github.com/jwaliszko/ExpressiveAnnotations

Comment: @godfathr OK, I had seen Expressive Annotations before and it looks promising. I'm apprehensive about using it though since this is a large legacy application and I have concerns about something breaking if I bring it in. I was hoping to find a way to use jQuery's validator component since ASP MVC already uses it and just modify the validation rules client side as needed.