# ASP MVC: Custom Validation Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, attributes

I'm trying to write my own Custom Validation attribute but I'm having some problems.

The attribute I'm trying to write is that when a user logs in, the password will be compared against the confirmation password.

```
namespace Data.Attributes
{
public class ComparePassword : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string PasswordToCompareWith { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (PasswordToCompareWith == (string)value)
        {
            return true;
        }
       return false;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when i'm trying to set the attribute like this in the model file:

```
 [Required]
    [ComparePassword(PasswordToCompareWith=ConfirmPassword)]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
   }
```

I get the following error:

> Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, 
>   or property 'Project.Data.Models.GebruikerRegistreerModel.ConfirmPassword.get'

It seems that VS is not accepting the `confirmpassword` in the `PasswordToCompareWith=ConfirmPassword` part.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint you but handling such a simple case like yours using Data Annotations could be a pain. You may take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280539/custom-model-validation-of-dependent-properties-using-data-annotations).

Answer (score 18):

According to this link http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-1 there is an special validation attribute now in MVC3:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    // skipped

    [Required]
    [ValidatePasswordLength]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }                       

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

> **CompareAttribute** is a new, very useful validator that is not actually
>   part of
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,
>   but has been added to the
>   System.Web.Mvc DLL by the team. Whilst
>   not particularly well named (the only
>   comparison it makes is to check for
>   equality, so perhaps EqualTo would be
>   more obvious), it is easy to see from
>   the usage that this validator checks
>   that the value of one property equals
>   the value of another property. You can
>   see from the code, that the attribute
>   takes in a string property which is
>   the name of the other property that
>   you are comparing. The classic usage
>   of this type of validator is what we
>   are using it for here: password
>   confirmation.

Comment: MSDN says this API has been obsolete. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.compareattribute(v=vs.118).aspx . They have apparently moved it under the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

FoolProof http://foolproof.codeplex.com/ seems to be the best solution.

```
public class SignUpViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [EqualTo("Password", ErrorMessage="Passwords do not match.")]
    public string RetypePassword { get; set; }
}
```

It is better than suggested PropertiesMustMatchAttribute as it adds the validation error for the "RetypePassword' instead of the global model level as PropertiesMustMatchAttribute does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this is made out to be such a big deal, just do this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class ComparePassword: ValidationAttribute
{
    public ComparePassword() 
        : base("Passwords must match.") { }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid (object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null) return new ValidationResult("A password is required.");

        // Make sure you change YourRegistrationModel to whatever  the actual name is
        if ((validationContext.ObjectType.Name != "YourRegistrationModel") 
             return new ValidationResult("This attribute is being used incorrectly.");
        if (((YourRegistrationModel)validationContext.ObjectInstance).ConfirmPassword != value.ToString())
            return new ValidationResult("Passwords must match.");

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is add `[ComparePassword]` to your password property, nothing to pass... simple and fairly clean

Comment: Super, but given the new CompareAttribute @orcy brought to our attention, it is unnecessary to roll out our own.

Comment: This is satisfactory demo code, but the obvious issue with this is reusability; It's hard-coded for a specific implementation (`YourRegistrationModel`) with a specific property (`ConfirmPassword`). If you want to use this approach with more than one Model, you'll need multiple instances or a base PasswordModel type/interface, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a reference type to an attribute unless you do some rather lame reflection code.

In this situation, I would think creating a custom model binder would be a better idea and then checking the Password and ComparePassword at that point.

Comment: I think that model binder is definitely more lame than using DataAnnotations with reflection. I believe that model binder should not define validation rules.

Comment: Hah, that's a huge discussion topic. I couldn't properly explain that is this short a space, but I can point you to a good resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you need a STATIC method in your case:
EXAMPLE:

```
        public static ValidationResult ValidateFrequency( double frequency, ValidationContext context )
    {
        if( context == null )
        {
            return ( ValidationResult.Success );
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just as an example:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
 using System.Globalization;
 using System.Web.Mvc;
 using System.Web.Security;

 namespace GDNET.Web.Mvc.Validation
 {
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private const string defaultErrorMessage = "'{0}' must be at least {1} characters long.";
    private readonly int minRequiredPasswordLength = Membership.Provider.MinRequiredPasswordLength;

    public ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute()
        : base(defaultErrorMessage)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, ErrorMessageString, name, minRequiredPasswordLength);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string valueAsString = value as string;
        return (valueAsString != null && valueAsString.Length >= minRequiredPasswordLength);
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule(FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()), minRequiredPasswordLength, int.MaxValue)
        };
    }
}
  }
```

source: https://code.google.com/p/gdnetprojects/source/browse/trunk/Experiments/Common/GDNET.Web.Mvc/Validation/ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute.cs?r=69