# trying to validate a year field in my model

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I am trying to validate a year field in my model for a credit card.  I want to grab the current year as the minimum value.  Here is my code:

```
[Required]
[Range(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Year+20, ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid year")] 
[Display(Name = "Exp. Year")]
public int expYear { get; set; }
```

The error I am getting is: "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type" on the "DateTime.Now.Year" code.

Comment: The exception message is fairly explicitly. What specifically don't you understand about it?

Comment: you can make a knockoff of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321948/is-there-a-range-attribute-for-datetime), it's almost a duplicate

Comment: @Jonesy That answer would not be much better than hard-coding the current year. The constructor of `RangeAttribute` is still only called once, so the years never update. The proper solution is to define a method that checks `DateTime.Now.Year` on every validation, e.g. through [CustomValidationAttribute](http://weblogs.asp.net/peterblum/archive/2009/12/07/the-customvalidationattribute.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.Year` is not a constant that can be compiled into the assembly and that is where the attributes go.

Comment: Well, I can't hard code 2014 in because next year that will change.

Comment: Check this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720735/asp-mvc-custom-validation-attribute). You may need to write a custom attribute and use a bit of reflection to fetch the limits. You can pass some constant string(s) to give your attribute idea where to obtain the required value or may by in your specific case you can do it just by using DateTime.Now inside your IsValid method in that attribute.