# asp.net mvc validation annotation for int either must be 0 or greater than 100000

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have an int that I want to validate with annotation in my model. It can be either 0 or greater than or equal to 100000. How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Share any code you may have so far and we can help attune the code to what works for your project.

Comment: There is no built-in annotation to do this. However should be easy to write a custom one

Comment: Good question. Humble suggestion: ["zero is not null"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134861/how-can-i-explain-the-difference-between-null-and-zero) Don't store zero when you mean nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP MVC: Custom Validation Attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720735/asp-mvc-custom-validation-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, there isn't one out of the box that does this that I am aware of, but there are several people that have written custom validation attributes that you can use. A good example that I have used in the past is from [Lessthan Greaterthan Validation](https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/11/05/asp-net-mvc-lessthan-and-greaterthan-validation-attributes/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to write custom annotation but why to bother :)
I highly recommend using [Fluent Validation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation)

Then solution for you problem would look like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Property)
                .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0)
                .LessThanOrEqualTo(100000)
                .WithMessage("must be in range of 0-100000");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IValidatableObject` and provide your own customized validation:

Something like:

```
public class MyModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        //todo implement your logic here
             yield return new ValidationResult("Must be 0 or >= 1000");
    }    
}
```

[IValidatableObject.Validate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Fluent Validation

```
using FluentValidation;
...

public class IntValidator : AbstractValidator<int>
{
    public IntValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Property)
                        .Equal(0).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(100000)
                        .WithMessage("must be  0 or greater than 100000");
    }
}
```

Then

```
int intvariable;
IntValidator validator=new IntValidator();
ValidationResult result= validator.Validate(intvariable);
```