# Custom Validation Attribute is not called ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Hello everyone I have create custom validation attribute and assign it to class level validation. Unfortunately, it is not called. I try every way that it think it could be solve the problem. However, it take me for hours and I can't find the attribute is not called by validation mechanism.

For illustrate you I put the following code.

Attribute:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class BooleanDependencyAttribute : ValidationAttribute {
    private const string _defaultErrorMessage = "กรุณากรอก{0}";
    private readonly object _typeId = new object();

    public string DependencyPropertyName { get; private set; }
    public string DependentPropertyName { get; private set; }

    public BooleanDependencyAttribute(string dependencyPropertyName,
                                      string dependentPropertyName)
        : base(_defaultErrorMessage) {
        DependencyPropertyName = dependencyPropertyName;
        DependentPropertyName = dependentPropertyName;
    }

    public override object TypeId {
        get { return _typeId; }
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name) {
        return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, ErrorMessageString,
                             name);
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value) {
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(value);
        bool dependencyValue =
            (bool)properties.Find(DependencyPropertyName, true /* ignoreCase */)
                .GetValue(value);
        object dependentValue =
            properties.Find(DependentPropertyName, true /* ignoreCase */)
                .GetValue(value);
        if (dependencyValue) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (dependentValue == null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```cs
[BooleanDependency("ReleaseNow", "ReleaseDate",
                   ErrorMessage = "Please enter release date")]
public class ContentCreate {
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public string Abstract { get; set; }

    public string Tags { get; set; }

    public bool ReleaseNow { get; set; }
}
```

Please could you help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 7):

I found the solution. In fact validation in class level is called after all property-level validations are valid. Therefore I need to complete other required property then BooleanDependencyAttribute will called and valid value.

Thanks for view, edit the title and tag.