# Is there a way through data annotations to verify that one date property is greater than or equal to another date property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I have a `StartDate` and `EndDate` on my `SchoolEvents` Model and I was wondering if there are any data annotations I could use to verify that the `StartDate` is less than or equal to the `EndDate` and that the `EndDate` is greater than or equal to the `StartDate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my point of view, you have to build a [custom validation attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.customvalidationattribute%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  You can look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280539/custom-model-validation-of-dependent-properties-using-data-annotations) to validate follow specific your validation. It will take your efforts so much.
Instead of you use data annotation you should apply [Fluent Validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/) which will help you reduce efforts. It is easy to setup, straight forward and separates of concern, you do not need mixing between view models, domain objects, and validations which depend on business rule.
Sample code using the CustomValidation in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

```
[CustomValidation(typeof(StartDateDateValidation), "ValidateStartDate")]
public class SampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

    public class StartDateDateValidation
    {
        public static ValidationResult ValidateStartDate(SampleModel sampleModel)
        {
        bool isValid = sampleModel.StartDate <= sampleModel.EndDate;

        if (isValid)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        
        return new ValidationResult(
            "The start date value must be smaller or equal the end date value. ");          
   }
```

Using Validator class in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to validate the object values:

```
SampleModel model = new SampleModel
{
     Id = 1,
     Name = "Test",
     StartDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1),
     EndDate = new DateTime(1992, 1, 1)
};

Validator.ValidateObject(model, new ValidationContext(model));
```

Using FluentValidation sample:

```
public class FluentSampleModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}

public class FluentSampleModelValidator : AbstractValidator<FluentSampleModel>
{
    public FluentSampleModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.StartDate <= x.EndDate);
    }
}
```

the sample for validation:

```
FluentSampleModel fluentModel = new FluentSampleModel()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Test",
    StartDate = new DateTime(1990, 1, 1),
    EndDate = new DateTime(1992, 1, 1)
};

FluentSampleModelValidator validator = new FluentSampleModelValidator();
var result = validator.Validate(fluentModel);

if (result != null && result.IsValid)
{
    // Handle valid data model
}
```

Comment: Your "Fluent Validation" link is dead as of right now.  which is why link only answers are now often removed or downvoted.

Comment: You should put example code using that IN your answer to protect against unrelated site updates or being in accessible state for any reason.  To be fair, the OP's question does not appear to contain enough details either including what has been attempted and if presented as a question today likely would have been quickly closed.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: I understand your POV. Anw, I update the answer with the example code.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve what you need by installing and using `foolproof` nuget package.

Install `foolproof` nuget package and use its extra useful attributes like the following:

```
public class EventViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [GreaterThan("Start")]
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

More examples of exactly what you need are [here](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/)

Comment: There is no support for MVC3+ on foolproof and the last version of it was in 2012